# add custom data in hovertemplate (plotly, shiny, r)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I would like to modify the label of a plotly-sankey diagram in a shiny app.

For example, I want to display 1/10 of the `value` in the `<extra>` box of a hover info.
Find below a minimum working example.

The manual says this about additional details in the `hovertemplate`:

> The variables available in `hovertemplate` are the ones emitted as
>   event data described at this link
>   https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#event-data. Additionally,
>   every attributes that can be specified per-point (the ones that are
>   `arrayOk: true`) are available.

Alternatively, I would be happy to divide by 10 in the `hovertemplate` string itself, if possible.

(Non-)working example:

```
rm(list = ls())

if(!require(pacman)) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(shiny, plotly)

# ui ----------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    plotlyOutput("sankey")
  )
)


# server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$sankey <- renderPlotly(

    plot_ly(
      type = "sankey",
      orientation = "h",

      node = list(
        label = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"),
        color = c("blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"),
        pad = 15,
        thickness = 20,
        line = list(
          color = "black",
          width = 0.5
        )
      ),

      link = list(
        source = c(0,1,0,2,3,3),
        target = c(2,3,3,4,4,5),
        value =  c(8,4,2,8,4,2),

        customInfo = c(8,4,2,8,4,2)/10,

        hovertemplate = "%{value}<extra>%{customInfo}</extra>"

      )
    ) %>% 
      layout(
        title = "Basic Sankey Diagram",
        font = list(
          size = 10
        )
      )

  )

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I think this is currently not possible. There are some plans for that: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4243